# "error: stray ‘\321’ in program" and "error: stray ‘\205’ in program"

Tags: c++, class

The program below keeps getting compilation errors on line 4. Why.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
enum Type { mp3=0, wav=1, ogg=2, flac=3 };
enum Kompresija { х264=0, Theora=1, AV1=2 }; //here!!!!

class MediaSegment{
protected:
    char naslov[100];
    char avtor[100];
    int vremetraenje;
    int golemina;
public:
```

Comment: Delete that line and retype it.  It (presumably) has some garbage characters in it.

Comment: This is a FAQ. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*. All questions of this type can be analysed in exactly the same way: The sequence of numbers (here 321 205) are (usually) octal. Convert them to hexadecimal and search for the UTF-8 sequence (here Unicode code point [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA](https://codepoints.net/U+0445), 0xD1 0x85). It can be searched directly (and replaced) by using regular expression search (in this case, using `\x{445}`) in text editors capable of search with regular expressions.

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 4):

The `x` in `x264` actually is a [Cyrillic Ha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kha_(Cyrillic)) (ĥ). Rendered in UTF-8:

321 205 (octal) = 0xD1 0x85 = Unicode code point [U+0445 (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER HA)](https://codepoints.net/U+0445) = Cyrillic х (not Latin x)

And C++ expects a basic Latin enum constant name.

Comment: Well spotted. I enjoy having more and more programs handling utf-8 everywhere on my system. Yet I am adamant to ensure my source files are 100% pure ASCII! If I can make the build fail (with a specific&useful error message) if an outsider is found, I do not hesitate.

Comment: In most text editors with regular expression matching it can be searched for by `\x{445}` (and replaced). For example, [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) (Linux and Windows), [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) (Windows), and [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) (Linux and Windows).

Comment: The notation is different in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (and others): `\u445`

Answer (score 0):

This bug is related to your compiler. It is usually a problem with special characters. It is possible, that you cannot see this character. I would try to rewrite the code, that makes this problem. But you may have other options as well.

Maybe this is a help for you:

Convert the file to ASCII and blast all Unicode characters away. It will probably work. But u never know, what was the problem. It will remove all Unicode characters like C²

You may damage some logic like "Smart-Quotes" (“ & ”) or a pointer with a full-width asterisk (＊).

More options for you: Maybe the current font cannot display the character. Switch fonts to see the character.

Or you try to find by an regular expression all Unicode characters, that are not part of non-extended ASCII.

[\x{80}-\x{FFFF}]

Hopefully this might help you

Comment: There isn't any need to retype anything. This can be analysed directly from the error messages (as [Joop Eggen did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755940/error-stray-321-in-program-and-error-stray-205-in-program/67756013#67756013))

Comment: Here is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to detect (and replace) the most common ones (e.g., works in [Geany](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/), [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), UltraEdit, and Visual Studio Code): `\x{00A0}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{FEFF}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2212}|\x{00E4}|\x{FFFC}|\x{FFFD}|\x{2217}|\x{200C}|\x{202B}|\x{202A}`.

Comment: cont' - Though once an offending character is detected, in some cases it is required to identify exactly which one it is in order to make the right decision for the replacement.

Comment: cont' - The Unicode characters are *[NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x)*, *[ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)*, *ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER*, *ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE*, *EN DASH*, *EM DASH*, *LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK*, *RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK*, *MINUS SIGN*, *LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS*, *OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER*, *REPLACEMENT CHARACTER*, *ASTERISK OPERATOR*, *POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING*, *RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING*, and *LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING*, respectively.

Comment: Some of them *may* be present as [CE/CP-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), not UTF-8. For example, `0xA0` instead of the UTF-8 byte sequence `0xC2 0xA0` for NO-BREAK SPACE. Other observed CE/CP-1250 ones are 0x91 (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), 0x92 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), and 0x96 (EN DASH).